# How to add a string on a specific string by using regex_replace method in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I am trying to add a string '_$' to a index name and a table name as follows. I need to use a method 'regexp_replace' in SELECT statement.
select regexp_replace(input_string......)

@ Input

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SCOTT"."PK_EMP" ON "SCOTT"."EMP" ("EMP_NO")
```

@ Desired Output

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SCOTT"."PK_EMP_$" ON "SCOTT"."EMP_$" ("EMP_NO")
```

Can you help me to build a regular expression for that?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on multiple columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly brute solution would be using the following pattern:

```
(.*)(" ON ".*)(" \(.*)
```

with the following replace string:

```
\1_$\2_$\3
```

The pattern works by splitting the input in the places where you need to insert the `_$` token, and then joining it back placing the tokens in the places we split the input:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SCOTT"."PK_EMP`**|**`" ON "SCOTT"."EMP`**|**`" ("EMP_NO")`

Full SELECT query would look like that:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
        'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SCOTT"."PK_EMP" ON "SCOTT"."EMP" ("EMP_NO")',
        '(.*)(" ON ".*)(" \(.*)',
        '\1_$\2_$\3'
       ) RX
  FROM dual;
```